# If $G(x)=\int{g(x)dx}$ then what is $\tilde{G}(x)=\int{|g(x)|dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let's say we have some function $g(x)$ continous $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $G(x)=\int{g(x)dx}$.

In this case what would $\int{|g(x)|dx}$ be equal to? What is the relationship between this integral, $\int{|g(x)|dx}$, and absolute value of $G(x)$, $|\int{g(x)dx}|$? What if we were calculating a definite integral on a segment $[a,b]$, then what would $\int_a^b{|g(x)|dx}$ be equal to with respect to $G(x)$?

Comment: For continuous functions, we have $| \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \mathrm{d}x| \le  \int_{a}^{b} |g(x)| \mathrm{d}x  $

Comment: @Scene how to prove that? Any links?

Comment: See: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_Value_of_Definite_Integral

Comment: The triangle inequality has already been stated. But if your function $g(x)$ changes sign, almost never can you relate $\int |g(x)|dx$ to $G(x)$.

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous, away from a $0$ of $g$ the two anti-derivatives will locally be in the same equivalence class (i.e. differ by a constant) or be additive opposites (you can work out for yourself when each case happens). This differs from the discontinuous case, in which the difference between the two anti-derivaitves is essentially arbitrary.

Comment: The fact underlying this assertion is that when $g$ is continuous, $A = \{x : g(x) > 0\}$ is an open set, which in $\mathbb{R}^1$ means that it is a countable disjoint union of open intervals. On $A$, $|g| = g$. Likewise, $B = \{x : g(x) < 0\}$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals on which $|g| = -g$. The key point is that continuity imposes heavy restrictions on what $A$ and $B$ can look like, and those sets control the difference between $g$ and $|g|$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins in your first comment, are you making an assumption that function is either even or odd? Or are you making an assumption that there are no intersections with x-axis on the interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: @bb_823 I'm talking about what happens near any point that is not a $0$ of $g$. I was talking about anti-derivatives because I didn't see that you also asked about definite integrals. But, of course, if there is not a $0$ of $g$ in $[a,b]$, then either $|g| = g$ or $|g| = -g$ on the entire interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments to my question written by Scene and Ted Shifrin I have concluded the following:

- $\left|\int_a^bg(x)dx\right|\le\int_a^b\left|g(x)\right|dx$

(*proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_Value_of_Definite_Integral*)

- If function $g(x)$ changes signs in most cases there is no relation between $G(x)$ and $\tilde{G}(x)$.